# Pyenv on Mac Ventura: Python curses extension was not compiled

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv

I'm trying to  use pyenv to install python 3.11 (pyenv seems like a great tool for managing multiple python versions on per-project basis).

**I am running on intel Ventura 13.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

When running

```bash
pyenv install 3.11
```

I get the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
WARNING: The Python curses extension was not compiled. Missing the ncurses lib?

#### What I've tried

Using ncurses installed via brew:

```bash
brew install ncurses
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix ncurses)/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"
pyenv install 3.11
```

Linking brew libraries [manually](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1755#issuecomment-743700308):

```bash
export CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix ncurses)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"

export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix ncurses)/lib -L$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/lib"

pyenv install 3.11
```

I've also reinstalled xcode-select and tried the above steps. What's more confusing to me is that I can see `ncurses.h` in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include.

#### How I installed pyenv

I installed pyenv via homebrew

```bash
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

then setup paths in my zshrc and zprofile

```bash
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

then installed python build dependencies

```bash
brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib tcl-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

Python version `3.11` is relatively new in the market, so some packages and libraries my not fully support `python3.11`. You may encounter compatibility issues, so be sure to check the documentation or go through online community chats.

**You may try the following few steps:**

- `brew upgrade pyenv`
- `brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib` (install dependencies required for py3.11)
- `$ pyenv install 3.11.0`
- `$ pyenv global 3.11.0` (set py3.11 global)

*You may also want to verify if the py3.11 is installed or not by doing,*

- `python --version`

If you still encounters error then check if the `python 3.11` is available for `pyenv` or not (since it is relatively new) by running the following script:

- `pyenv install -l` (this will give the list of all available versions)

For more visit [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#install-python-build-dependencies)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. I also checked and I’m getting the same error when trying to install Python 3.10.

Comment: Then its better to use Anaconda or miniconda